# Lock a nexus 7 to only one wifi network

Tags: android

We are using a nexus 7 in a very limited way and want some features removed/locked.

One problem we are having is the the device needs to be on a wifi network we set up. Thsi works fine as we save the details for it but if somone accesses the wifi menu and changes the network it will stop the device from working as intended.

Is there a way to set the nexus 7 so that it will not connect to any other wifi network ?

maybe some kind of banned network list ?

This is not an issue of it auto connecting to another network when our network is off but of a user changing the network because they want internet access on the device which we do not want them to have.

Comment: Why this offtopic? This is really valid question, in future if this off topic becomes a feature????

Comment: As the nexus devices are intended to permit experimentation with the source code of Android itself, this is on topic as a programming question

Comment: @ChrisStratton Writing a custom build of Android to implement this is far too broad for a an SO answer; and had it been asking for a configuration setting, there's [the android SE site](http://android.stackexchange.com/) for that.

Comment: I posted a comment intended to suggest a productive direction towards resolving the problem.  I did not post an "answer".  There **are no** configuration settings for this, but a *programmer* can accomplish the task by creating some.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do what you're talking about would be to make your own, custom build of Android that would lock down the features that you don't want.

Comment: so there is no control over the way it connects to wifi at all, i find it hard to believe that there are no setting options at all

Comment: The settings are all user modifiable.  There is no way to lock down the users ability to connect to what ever network they choose.